# Make part of coroutine continue past cancellation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a file managing class that can save a big file. The file manager class is an application singleton, so it outlives my UI classes. My Activity/Fragment can call the `save` suspend function of the file manager from a coroutine and then show success or failure in the UI. For example:

```
//In MyActivity:
private fun saveTheFile() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    try {
        myFileManager.saveBigFile()
        myTextView.text = "Successfully saved file"
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        myTextView.text = "Failed to save file"
    }
}

//In MyFileManager
suspend fun saveBigFile() {
    //Set up the parameters
    //...

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //Save the file
        //...
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I don't want the save operation to be aborted if the Activity is finished. If the activity is destroyed before the `withContext` block gets going, or if the `withContext` block has any suspension points in it, then saving will not be completed because the coroutine will be canceled.

What I want to happen is that the file is always saved. If the Activity is still around, then we can show UI updates on completion.

I thought one way to do it might be to start a new `coroutineScope` from the suspend function like this, but this scope still seems to get cancelled when its parent job is cancelled.

```
suspend fun saveBigFile() = coroutineScope {
    //...
}
```

I thought another alternative might be to make this a regular function that updates some LiveData when it's finished. The Activity could observe the live data for the result, and since LiveData automatically removes lifecycle observers when they're destroyed, the Activity is not leaked to the FileManager. I'd like to avoid this pattern if the something less convoluted like the above can be done instead.

```
//In MyActivity:
private fun saveTheFile() {
    val result = myFileManager.saveBigFile()
    result.observe(this@MyActivity) {
        myTextView.text = when (it) {
            true -> "Successfully saved file"
            else -> "Failed to save file"
        }
    }
}

//In MyFileManager
fun saveBigFile(): LiveData<Boolean> {
    //Set up the parameters
    //...
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    MainScope().launch {
        val success = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //Save the file
            //...
        }
        liveData.value = success
    }
    return liveData
}
```

Comment: Probably you should do such work in service which needs to be completed even your Activity/app gets killed. Because coroutine are just like threads whose lifecycle depends upon the process in which it's running. Service make you gurantee that your work will be completed and will not be affected on activity/app killed.

Comment: A service also runs in your application and so it's not guaranteed to be protected from killing. If you make it a foreground service, it becomes unlikely to be killed. But I've never seen any app ever that starts a foreground service just to save a file. In all likelihood, a file operation will not take long enough to be at risk of the application being torn down to conserve RAM.

Comment: Another approach could be to use workmanager which doesn't get affected with app kill or restart.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the bit that you don't want to be cancelled with `NonCancellable`.

```
// May cancel here.
withContext(Dispatchers.IO + NonCancellable) {
    // Will complete, even if cancelled.
}
// May cancel here.
```

Comment: From the documentation, it looks like that should work. But I'm starting to get the feeling that it's a big code smell to have any coroutine that does not play nice with cancellation. The documentation for NonCancellable implies that it's something you should only very rarely need, and only in a `finally` block. It seems like an unexpected behavior for a coroutine to ignore cancellation requests. Perhaps the LiveData is the best way to handle this.

Comment: Good video of cancellation from Kotlinconf including NonCancellable https://youtu.be/w0kfnydnFWI?t=1160

Comment: If you need to do something that is atomic, that must not cancel halfway through, then you're in one of the rare cases. Temporarily preventing cancellation is fine, just make sure your coroutines are scoped.

Answer (score 1):

If you have code whose lifetime is scoped to the lifetime of the whole application, then this is a use case for the `GlobalScope`. However, just saying `GlobalScope.launch` is not a good strategy because you could launch several concurrent file operations that may be in conflict (this depends on your app's details). The recommended way is to use a globally-scoped `actor`, in the role of an executor service.

Basically, you can say

```
@ObsoleteCoroutinesApi
val executor = GlobalScope.actor<() -> Unit>(Dispatchers.IO) {
    for (task in channel) {
        task()
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
private fun saveTheFile() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    executor.send {
        try {
            myFileManager.saveBigFile()
            withContext(Main) {
                myTextView.text = "Successfully saved file"
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            withContext(Main) {
                myTextView.text = "Failed to save file"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is still not a great solution, it retains `myTextView` beyond its lifetime. Decoupling the UI notifications from the view is another topic, though.

`actor` is labeled as "obsolete coroutines API", but that's just an advance notice that it will be replaced with a more powerful alternative in a future version of Kotlin. It doesn't mean it's broken or unsupported.

Comment: Would we get the same results as you described by using a CoroutineScope created for the lifetime of the file manager (which is a singleton that lives for the app's life)? Regarding your example, if I didn't care about leaking the Activity's views, I wouldn't need to worry about cancellation in the first place--I would use something other than lifecycleScope to launch this job.

Comment: As for the first point, you can always write `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)`, but that still leaves the leakage problem. You have to remove all references to the view from the submitted background job, and that usually means using MVVM so you can refer to the ViewModel instead.

Comment: @MarkoTopoInk, do you have a recommended way to handle the `@ObsoleteCoroutinesApi` annotation? I don't want to propagate this annotation throughout my code, but rather confine it to where I'm directly using the actor, so I can revise the API someday when actors are deprecated. Is the only way to do that to simply not use the annotation and leave the warning as is, or is there a way to suppress it on this class or function only?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it appears to do what I described that I wanted. The FileManager class has its own scope, though I suppose it could also be GlobalScope since it's a singleton class.

We launch a new job in its own scope from the coroutine. This is done from a separate function to remove any ambiguity about the scope of the job. I use `async`
for this other job so I can bubble up exceptions that the UI should respond to.

Then after launch, we await the async job back in the original scope. `await()` suspends until the job is completed and passes along any throws (in my case I want IOExceptions to bubble up for the UI to show an error message). So if the original scope is cancelled, its coroutine never waits for the result, but the launched job keeps rolling along until it completes normally. Any exceptions that we want to ensure are always handled should be handled within the async function. Otherwise, they won't bubble up if the original job is cancelled.

```
//In MyActivity:
private fun saveTheFile() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    try {
        myFileManager.saveBigFile()
        myTextView.text = "Successfully saved file"
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        myTextView.text = "Failed to save file"
    }
}

class MyFileManager private constructor(app: Application):
    CoroutineScope by MainScope() {

    suspend fun saveBigFile() {
        //Set up the parameters
        //...

        val deferred = saveBigFileAsync()
        deferred.await()
    }

    private fun saveBigFileAsync() = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //Save the file
        //...
    }
}
```